# Title not appearing in pdf

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am iterating through files in folder and for each file I am plotting the close_price on x-axis and date on y-axis.

here is code.Everything is working fine except I want title "abc" to appear on each page but it not coming. What am I doing wrong here.

```
import os
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import  pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pp = PdfPages('multipage.pdf')

pth = "D:/Technical_Data/"
for fle in os.listdir(pth):
    df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(pth, fle),usecols=(0, 4))
    if not df.empty:
        df=df.astype(float)
        plt.title("abc")
        df.plot()
        pp.savefig()
pp.close()
```

Comment: [Here](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.title) is the documentation on pyplot title. It appears you need more arguments.

Comment: [read the funny manual](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the title as an argument of the `plot()` method, like:

```
import os
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import  pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pp = PdfPages('multipage.pdf')

pth = "D:/Technical_Data/"
for fle in os.listdir(pth):
    df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(pth, fle),usecols=(0, 4))
    if not df.empty:
        df=df.astype(float)
        df.plot(title="abc")
        pp.savefig()
pp.close()
```

Another way would be to put `plt.title("abc")` after `df.plot()`. Currently, your title `"abc"` was overwritten by the default title of `df.plot()`… which is `None`.